# accessing an array gives weird "refimpl"

Tags: vue.js

[image: Look of code]

[image: Console image]

I can't do data._rawValue or data._value to only get the arrays.
It doesn't recognize these keywords.

How should I approach this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about `data.value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a sample.

```js
   const data = ref([{ name: 1 }, { name: 2 }]);

    const testClick = function () {
      for (const item in data.value) {
        console.log(data.value[item]);
        console.log("hello");
      }
      console.log(data);
    };
    onMounted(() => {
      testClick();
    });
```

I think you may wrap the data with the ref function from vue.
Therefore,everytime you want to read the value from data,you had to read from the (data.value).
I suggest you to check the offical document of vue.
https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref
Besides,if the type of data is object or array,its better to wrap it with reactive function.And then you can just read it directly.
I used to feel puzzle about this situation,too.
Im not good at writing in english.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/alex.sabbir.7927

```
const data = ref([{ name: 1 }, { name: 2 }]);

const testClick = function () {
  for (const item in data.value) {
    console.log(data.value[item]);
    console.log("hello");
  }
  console.log(data);
};
onMounted(() => {
  testClick();
});
```

Comment: For what there is a Facebook like on top?